# Databricks "Format document" not adding newline to end of file

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, python-black

I'm using Databricks Runtime 13.3 LTS ML and for some reason the "Format document" black formatting is not adding a newline to the end of (python) file.

However, running same version of black locally, the newline is added.

Is there a way to force Databricks to add the newline?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the newline is added to the file when you format the document, but in Databricks, when you check, it seems like a newline is not added.

Below is the code in `.py` in local.

```py
from typing import Union
from fastapi import FastAPI

app = FastAPI()
@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}
@app.get("/items/")
def read_item(item_id: int, q: Union[str, None] = None):
    return {"item_id": item_id, "q": q}
```

After re-formatting, you will see 15 lines, and the 15th is the newline.

[image]

But the same thing in Databricks shows 14 lines like below after re-formatting.

[image]

This is because whenever you calculate the number of lines, it gives a count of 1 less than expected, as it only counts when it reads the `\n` character. In line 15, there is no `\n` character, so it gives 14, but when you check it in an `IDE`, you will see newline. However, internally, the newline is added in both Databricks and locally.